# cannot get currentUser id (from homePage) to an another widget (timeline) in flutter-firebase App

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a social network app using flutter-firebase. whenever i restart my app the terminal shows the following error.

```
E/flutter ( 3184): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'id' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 3184): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 3184): Tried calling: id
E/flutter ( 3184): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 3184): #1      _TimelineState.getTimeline (package:enviral/pages/timeline.dart:47:33)
E/flutter ( 3184): #2      _TimelineState.initState (package:enviral/pages/timeline.dart:28:5)
E/flutter ( 3184): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
E/flutter ( 3184): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter ( 3184): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 3184): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 3184): #7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
```

**this is my timeline widget:**

```
inal usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
  final User currentUser;

  Timeline({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {
  List<Post> posts;
  List<String> followingList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTimeline();
    getFollowing();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: header(context, isAppTitle: true),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () => getTimeline(), child: buildTimeline()));
  }

  getTimeline() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await timelineRef
        .doc(widget.currentUser.id)
        .collection('timelinePosts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .get();
    List<Post> posts =
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }

  getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
        .doc(currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .get();
    setState(() {
      followingList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList();
    });
  }

  buildTimeline() {
    if (posts == null) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else if (posts.isEmpty) {
      return buildUsersToFollow();
    } else {
      return ListView(children: posts);
    }
  }

  buildUsersToFollow() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream:
          usersRef.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).limit(30).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<UserResult> userResults = [];
        snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
          User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
          final bool isAuthUser = currentUser.id == user.id;
          final bool isFollowingUser = followingList.contains(user.id);
          // remove auth user from recommended list
          if (isAuthUser) {
            return;
          } else if (isFollowingUser) {
            return;
          } else {
            UserResult userResult = UserResult(user);
            userResults.add(userResult);
          }
        });
        return Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.2),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.person_add,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Users to Follow",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(children: userResults),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**my HomePage widget is where I called Timeline as follows.**

```
Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Timeline(currentUser: currentUser),
          ActivityFeed(),
          Upload(currentUser: currentUser),
          Search(),
          Profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          currentIndex: pageIndex,
          onTap: onTap,
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.photo_camera,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
          ]),
    );
    // return RaisedButton(
    //   child: Text('Logout'),
    //   onPressed: logout,
    // );
  }
```

error shows that the problem lies somewhere in **getTimeline()** and **getFollowing()** methods more pricisely when called inside **initState()**

please someone help me with it. it's almost 3 days since i am stuck.

Comment: If you just want to save the `id` of the user locally on the device, you can use the `SharedPreferences` package.

Comment: On your code, you are calling for 'id' which I suppose is the user ID, however this is being done before the ID is stablished so that is why is being marked as null, to confirm where is the issue, just log the content of 'ID' everytime before is called.